# List contains method returns false when using Math.sqrt() as a parameter

Tags: java, arraylist, contains, math.sqrt

I am refreshing my knowledge in Java and working on an exercise from codewars. The problem is to compare two arrays if the elements are the "same". The meaning of "same" is that the elements in 'b' are the elements in 'a' squared, regardless of the order. The solution that I was trying to do is to get the square root of element in 'b' and check if it does exists in element 'a' using Math.sqrt(). However, when I use that as a parameter for contains(), it always returns false.

So to check if the square root of element 'b' really does exists in 'a', I tried a simple if-else to check a specific element. But when I incorporate it with Math.sqrt(), that's where the problem rise.

Here's the elements of set a and b

```
int[] a = {121, 144, 19, 161, 19, 144, 19, 11};
int[] b = {121, 14641, 20736, 361, 25921, 361, 20736, 361};
```

That I have converted to List

```
List<Integer> setAList = Arrays.stream(setA)//int[] setA - parameter of a function
                                                    .boxed()
                                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Integer> setBList = Arrays.stream(setB)//int[] setB - parameter of a function
                                                    .boxed()
                                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I converted the array to List to take advantage of contains() method. 
This is my code when I tried to check the specific element

```
double sqrd = Math.sqrt(setBList.get(6));
return setAList.get(5) == sqrd ? true : false;
```

And that gave an expected result - true.
Now here's the code of when I incorporated it to a for loop

```
boolean same = true;

for(int indexB : setB) {
    same = setAList.contains(Math.sqrt(indexB)) ? true : false; 
    System.out.println(Math.sqrt(indexB) + " " + same);

}
```

And here's the result

```
11.0 false
121.0 false
144.0 false
19.0 false
161.0 false
19.0 false
144.0 false
19.0 false
false
```

At first I though the problem might be because of the data types but I have tried casting the double to int but I'm still getting the same result.

Comment: your list contains Integers, you are checking whether it contains doubles, of course it doesn't.

Comment: As a side note, it would be easier to square the elements in `a` and check if they are in `b` (using the multiplication, not the Math.pow method, this way you only deal with ints).

Comment: Yes @Bentaye , that's my second option as of now. I will have to drop the int[] being converted to List as well, and to manipulate it using 'traditional' for loop.

Comment: @iamLinker Actually I just dropped an answer showing how to do it with streams, see below

Comment: Looking up *exact* floating point values, as is done in `contains()`, is a bad idea most of the time due to the limited precision of floating point values; you can try yourself and see for which numbers `Math.sqrt( number ) * Math.sqrt( number )` is *not* the same as `number`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Not a direct answer, but a workaround to avoid this kind of issues:**

As explained in other answers, your problem is a cast problem because you have to deal with `double` and `int` values and won't have to face casting issues.

A way to avoid it is to square values in A instead of calculating the square roots of values in B. This way you only ever deal with `int` values

```
int[] a = {121, 144, 19, 161, 19, 144, 19, 11};
int[] b = {121, 14641, 20736, 361, 25921, 361, 20736, 361};

// Make a list containing the squares out of the b array
List<Integer> squares = Arrays.stream(b)
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

// square all the values in B,
// and check that all the resultant values are present in the squares list
boolean same = Arrays.stream(a) // Stream<Integer> containing values in array a
    .map(i -> i* i) // Stream<Integer> containing values in array a squared
    .allMatch(squares::contains); // reduce to a boolean insuring that all values in the Stream<Integer> are present in the squares list

System.out.println(same);
```

Comment: Thanks! I will have to study your answer to have a better understanding.

Comment: @iamLinker I added  comments in the code, just ask if you don't get something

Answer (score 1):

`setAList.get(5) == sqrd` gives you the expected result because of [the widening primitive conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) of `setAList.get(5)` (which is an `int`) to a `double`.

If you've got `setAList.contains(Math.sqrt(indexB))`, you need to do the cast manually: `setAList.contains((int)Math.sqrt(indexB))`.

Comment: I have tried doing that but the problem with that is, it will omit the decimals. Let's say, we change one element to "132" which has a square root of "11.489125293076057", omitting its decimals will give us a desired result but it won't really solve the problem. Well maybe I need to look for another workaround for this one. Thanks Andrew!

Comment: @iamLinker what's the problem then?

Comment: I was aiming to use the result of Math.sqrt() to easily compare if element a is the same with element b. And by "same", here, means that the elements in 'b' are the elements in 'a' squared, regardless of the order.

Comment: @iamLinker then `11.489125293076057` should be defined in the list instead of `11`. Make `a` and `b` a `double[]`

Answer (score 0):

Looking up *exact* floating point values, as is done in `contains()`, is a bad idea most of the time due to the limited precision of floating point values; you can try yourself and see for which numbers `Math.sqrt( number ) * Math.sqrt( number )` is *not* the same as `number`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  final double r = Math.sqrt(i);
  final double s = r * r;
  if (s != i) {
    System.out.println(i + " != " + s);
  }
}
```

(Prints out 51 non-equal roots-squared out of the 100 numbers tested.)